# Playing audio with NodeJS: Illegal Audio-MPEG-Header

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio

I'm trying to play audio mp3 file from webserver without downloading it to the filesystem. This is how I get this file and play it:

```
var url = require('url');
var http = require('http');
var player = require('./player.js');

function initPlayback(res) {
   player.play(res);
   player.onPlaybackEnds(function() {
       console.log('Playback ends.');
   });
}

exports.add = function(file_url) {
   var options = {
       host: url.parse(file_url).host,
       port: 80,
       path: url.parse(file_url).pathname
   };
   http.get(options, function(res) {
       initPlayback(res);
   });
};
```

**player.js**:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var lame = require('lame');
var Speaker = require('speaker');

var options = {
    audio: {
        channels: 2,
        bitDepth: 16,
        sampleRate: 44100
    }
};

var decoderMp3 = lame.Decoder();
var speaker = new Speaker(options);

var onPlaybackEnds = function() {};

function playMp3(dataStream) {
    speaker = new Speaker(options);
    decoderMp3 = lame.Decoder();
    dataStream.pipe(decoderMp3).pipe(speaker);

    speaker.on('flush', function() {
        onPlaybackEnds();
    });
}

exports.play = function(dataStream) {
    playMp3(dataStream);
};

exports.onPlaybackEnds = function(callback) {
    onPlaybackEnds = callback;
};
```

The output I got from running the `add("http://localhost/file.mp3")` is:

```
Note: Illegal Audio-MPEG-Header 0x41504554 at offset 201915.
Note: Trying to resync...
Note: Hit end of (available) data during resync.
Playback ends.
```

It seems that before `flush` event some error happens. Track plays until the end. Yet when I try to run the same thing, it doesn't even start. Any ideas?

Comment: First make sure that the file and the lame decoder are compatible, i.e. lame can correctly decode the audio codec in mp3 file.

Comment: It sounds like your LAME decoder is having trouble reading from a stream.  Which lame package are you using?

Comment: I used NodeJS under Win7, so the LAME decoder should be that one from a box. This is an old project so I cannot tell for sure, but I cannot remember linking third-party libs to it. ``npm install`` only.

Comment: I have the exact same issue using https://github.com/guo-yu/player , anybody got an answer?